# jQuery UI : Problem with datepicker on smartphones

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I created a web site in `ASP.NET Core MVC`, using `bootstrap` and `jquery-ui`. The site works well in a desktop.

However in a smartphone, when I want to pick a date with `jquery-ui datepicker`, the calendar window appears in the wrong position…, outside of the partial window that contains the date input.

My View is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group" }))
{
    <table id="ProdTable" class="table">
        <tbody id="ProdTable">
            @foreach (var p in Model)
            {
                <tr id="tableRow" data-key="@p.lineid">
                    <td><input asp-for="@p.paData" type="date"
                               class="appDatePickClass" autocomplete="off" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // setting the Date Picker that I want.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".appDatePickClass").attr('type', 'text');

            $(".appDatePickClass").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
            });
        });
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this work around to adjust position of datepicker after it opens (please adjust position as per your requirement)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function(){ 
        $("#appDatePickClass").datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}); 
        // bind click event and adjust datepicker position.
        $(".hasDatepicker").click(function(e){
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").css({'top':e.pageY+20,'left':e.pageX-250});
        });
  });
</script>
```

and make sure you have :

at top.